# How to prove the Inequality expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

is it possible to prove the two expression :

1. $if  (\ 0\le\ a\le1\ \ ,\ 0\le\ b\le1,\ 0\le\ c\le1)$
   $ ,(\  a\le\ b\le\ c\ )\ ,\ and\ (\ a+b+c=1)$

*Then :* 
**$ a^2+b^2-ab\le\ a^2+c^2-ac$**

2. $if  (\ 0\le\ a\le1\ \ ,\ 0\le\ b\le1,\ 0\le\ c\le1)$
   $ ,(a\geq\ b\geq\ c)\ ,\ and\ (\ a+b+c=1)$

*Then :* 
$ a^2+b^2-ab\le\ a^2+c^2-ac$

Comment: What attempt have you made. Tell us where you got stuck. (Hint: 1) is true and 2) is false).

Comment: Thank you  Kavi Rama Murthy. I thought maybe the second one is not true and I have to prove it

Comment: Take $a=\frac  1 2,b=\frac  1 3,c=\frac  1 6$.

Comment: I have tested them, it is true